# Change colour of acronyms only with glossaries package

Tags: luatex, glossaries, acronyms

I use `\acrshort` for acronyms I've defined with the package `glossaries`. I want to keep the hyperref link for acronyms but I would like to change the colour : black for acronyms when they appear in text and keep blue for other hyperlinks.

I found the command `\renewcommand` but I don't manage to use it properly  I guess.
I tried: `\renewcommand*{\acrshort}[1]{\textcolor{black}{#1}}`

Here's a MWE, I tried to delete as much as possible what was not needed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside, openright]{book}
%\pdfobjcompresslevel 0 
% Language packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}              
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     

\usepackage[frenchb, english]{babel} 
\usepackage[]{csquotes}     
        
                 
\usepackage{lipsum}
                                              
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}                
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[backref = page, bookmarks = true, colorlinks = true, linkcolor = RoyalBlue, citecolor = RoyalBlue]{hyperref} % citation  

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{mylightblue1}{RGB}{235, 242, 249} % light blue for boxes
\definecolor{mylightblue2}{RGB}{118, 166, 214} % contour for boxes 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                          
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}    

\newacronym{mqi}{MQI}{\textit{Morphological Quality Index}}

\makeglossaries

\usepackage[graphicx]{realboxes}


\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{times}

% Biblio
\usepackage{natbib} 
\bibliographystyle{apalike-fr}  

% Start of script
\begin{document}
    
    \lipsum[1-2]
    
    The \acrshort{mqi} is new a morphological index used in Italy to measure the morphological status of waterbodies. 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be best if you provided a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/273733) so that it makes it easier to help. If you just delete everything that is not essential then paste it here, then it copied onto our systems and help will be quicker.

Comment: provide a MWE: a *small* but *complete* example.

Comment: Please provide a MWE, as usual. Since the M is for "minimal", you should remove everything that isn't related to the problem but is enough for the document to remain compilable. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found the way to change the color of acronyms:

```
\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\textcolor{Black}{#1}}
```

To add after the `glossaries` package is loaded and also explained in this post, that I've found after posting my question.
It works with the command of type `\gls` or `\acrshort`.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this - if you don't capitalize the color it works perfectly! I just made one line in the package header like this:

```
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\textcolor{black}{#1}}
```